# Inputstreamreader and data encoding

Tags: java, android, tcpclient, datainputstream, inputstreamreader

In my TCP client I receive a TCP message when my program is in state=0 i know that the data that i Receive are in UTF-8 and a text message will be received so i store my data stream to:

```
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis, "UTF-8"));
```

when I receive a specific msg e.g "XXX" i know that the next message will be a part of a BMP file.

How can i modify the input in order to receive the data and not convert them to "UTF-8"?

A part of my client:

```
   public void run() {

    mRun = true;
    state = ST_RECEIVEMSG;
    try {
        //here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        try {

            //send the message to the server
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

            //receive the message which the server sends back

            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            // The buffer reader cannot can't wrap an InputStream directly. It wraps another Reader.
            // So inputstreamreader is used.
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis, "UTF-8"));

            Log.d("MyApp","We are here");

            //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
            while (mRun) {

                if (state == ST_RECEIVEMSG) {

                    // The packet contains a message

                    Log.d("MyApp", "We are here 2");
                    serverMessage = input.readLine();

                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);

                        Log.d("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");
                    }

                    if ("XXX".equals(serverMessage)) {
                        // The next message will be the BMP image
                        Log.d("MyApp", "We are here 4");
                        state = ST_RECEIVEBMP;
                    }

                } else {

                    // The packet is part of BMP file

                    Log.d("MyApp", "We are here 5");

                    // Save the stream in a file

                    try {

                        Log.d("MyApp", "We are here 6");

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Log.e("TCP", "S: Error at file write", e);

                    }
                }

            }


        } finally {
            socket.close();

        }
        Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

    } finally {
        //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
        // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.

    }

}

//Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
//class at on asynckTask doInBackground
public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(String message);
}
```

}

Comment: Do not use Readers to begin with. They are for texts. BMP files have no text encoding either. Just read from the DataInputStream directly.

Comment: @greenapps reading from the datainput directly   (                        serverMessage = dis.readLine();) gives me the following suggestion/warning from the debugger : readLine() is depracted but it works...

Comment: Then do not use readLine(). It's very easy to make a readLine() function yourself. Just read bytes one by one until you read a '\n'. But if it works... use it. Who comes later then cares... First make your program working. And then you forget about it...

Comment: Ae you sending "XXX\n<bytes of file>" ? Do you want to read XXX from that line?

Comment: Eclipse: This method cannot be trusted to convert bytes to characters correctly. So if you send XXX be sure that you send three bytes. Stick to ANSI/ASCII to begin with.

Comment: The XXX is a text message that is sent from the server to indicate that the next message will be the bmp file. So I'll know hat the next message sould not be read as a text ... Anyway with the usage of dis.readlind() all my messages are read correctly. but my next issue is to receive the packets of the bmp file...

Comment: How do you knof the end of the file bytes stream? What kind of protocol do you have further?

Comment: I'll receive 320X240 bmp image, so I know the length of the total byte stream. Additionally each tcp packet that I'll receive i want to save it to the same file. As a result in the end I'll have the total bmp file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124165/discussion-between-g-v-and-greenapps).